# integer solutions of an equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Now I came with an equation to find the solutions in integers. Not aonly that, I would like to know other types of solutions (if exists). Find the solutions and method of solving the equation $p^3 - 2pqr = q^3 + r^3$. Where the $p, q, r$ may be integers.

Comment: either two are odd and one is even, or all three are even

Comment: Why do you want to solve this Diophantine equation?

Comment: @F'OlaYinka! there is no restriction on even and odd. I am looking integral solutions and the method of solving such equations. Kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: @vmr, F'Ola is saying every solution satisfies those restrictions. Can't you see why there can't possibly be a solution with all three odd?

Comment: @GerryMyerson!I know it. I said, how you can determine those solutions in numerical. The solutions may be odd, does not matter. How to solve such equation to list all the solutions (may be odd).

Comment: @JonahSinick! This only my out most interest. nothing else.

Comment: @vmr I have corrected the LaTeX in your question. You need to put the dollar sounds around complete formulae, rather than individual parts of formulae.

Comment: @OldJohn! Thank you for editing

Comment: @vmrfdu123456 , you seem to be missing big time what both F'Ola and Gerry told you: as a first, rather important, step to solve your equation, you have to realize that it **must** be that either two of the numbers in an eventual solutions **must** be odd and one even, or else all three **must** be even. If you don't understand this then you'll hardly understand an eventual solution to your problem.

Comment: @ vmrfdu123456, Why this particular Diophantine equation rather than another?

Comment: @DonAntonio! I understand that, please explain the method to get  such solutions, when two of them are odd.

Comment: A maple search didn't find any solutions where $p,q,r$ are between $-100$ and $100$ (except for the trivial solutions where $pqr=0$ and the nonzero have same magnitude).

Answer (score 3):

This defines a cubic curve with a rational point and hence an elliptic curve. It is birational to Cremona's 19A1 which has rank $0$ and precisely $3$ rational points. Tracing these back to the original equation leaves one with precisely the trivial solutions, 
$$
(p,q,r)=(k,0,k), (k,k,0) \mbox{ and } (0,k,-k)
$$
for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.